# How to improve Javascript performance

Tags: javascript

I know the title is quite generic but I am inserting 1 Million records into a AWS DynamoDB and currently it takes `~30 minutes to load`.
I have the 1 Million records in memory, I just need to improve the speed to insert the items. AWS only allows to send batches of 25 records but I all my code in syncronous.

Usually my data has a very small amount of data in the object (e.g. like 3-5 properties with number ids)

I read the 1 million entries from a CSV and basically store it in `data` array
Then I do this:

```
await DatabaseHandler.batchWriteItems('myTable', data); // data length is 1 Million
```

Which calls my insert function

```js
const documentClient = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

export class DatabaseHandler {

    static batchWriteItems = async (tableName: string, data: {}[]) => {
        // AWS only allows batches of max 25 items
        while (data.length) {
            const batch = data.splice(0, 25);
            const putRequests = batch.map((elem => {              
                return {
                    PutRequest: {
                        Item: elem
                    }
                };
            });
            const params = {
                RequestItems: {
                    [tableName]: putRequests,
                },
            };
            
            await documentClient.batchWrite(params).promise();
        }
    }
}
```

I believe I am doing `40,000 HTTP requests to create 25 records in the database`
Is there any way to improve this? Even some ideas would be great

Comment: I don't use AWS, but can it handle multiple requests at the same time?..  If so I would use a promise.map with concurrency..

Comment: Why are you not doing a bulk import? Seems like you are approaching this the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is "blocking", in the sense that you're waiting for the previous batch to execute before executing the next one. This is not the nature of JavaScript, and you're not taking advantage of promises. Instead, you can send all your requests at once, and JS' asynchronism will kick in and do all the work for you, which will be significantly faster:

```js
// in your class method:
const proms = []; // <-- create a promise array
while (data.length) {
  const batch = data.splice(0, 25);
  const putRequests = batch.map((elem => {
      return {
        PutRequest: {
          Item: elem
        }
      };
    });
    const params = {
      RequestItems: {
        [tableName]: putRequests,
      },
    };

    proms.push(documentClient.batchWrite(params).promise()); // <-- add the promise to our array
  }
}

await Promise.all(proms); // <-- wait for everything to be resolved asynchronously, then be done
```

This will speed up your request monumentally, as long as AWS lets you send that many concurrent requests.

---

I'm not sure how exactly you implemented the code, but to prove that it works, here's a dummy implementation (expect to wait about a minute):

```js
const request = (_, t = 5) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, t)); // implement a dummy request API

// with your approach
async function a(data) {
    while(data.length) {
        const batch = data.splice(0, 25);
        await request(batch);
    }
}

// non-blocking
async function b(data) {
    const proms = [];
    while(data.length) {
        const batch = data.splice(0, 25);
        proms.push(request(batch));
    }
    await Promise.all(proms);
}

(async function time(a, b) {
    const data = Array(10000).fill(); // create some dummy data (10,000 instead of a million or you'll be staring at this demo for a while)
    
    console.time("original");
    await a(data);
    console.timeEnd("original");

    console.time("optimized");
    await b(data);
    console.timeEnd("optimized");
})(a, b);
```

Comment: `await Promise.all(proms);`,  with 40,000 requests all fired off a the same time, can't see that been an issue at all. :)

Comment: @Keith ;) is it just me or are the braces messed up? It's quite confusing.

Comment: The performance is pretty much the same. Just tested it

Comment: @TiagoSilva are you sure? How did you implement it? Check the updated answer.